# Populate form data from 1 resource then update data to another source when submit in React-admin + Graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

How can i populate form data from 1 resource then update data to another source use Edit component and SimpleForm of react-admin?

I want to update to source name `event_source_measurement_protocol_description_updated` rather than `source_measurement_protocol`. Which i currently used for populated current data of form field

I'm currently using react-admin v4.1.0

```
export const SourceMeasurementProtocolUpdateDescription = () => (
  <Edit resource="source_measurement_protocol">
    <SimpleForm>
      <ReferenceInput
        source="source_measurement_protocol_id"
        reference="source_measurement_protocol"
      >
        <AutocompleteInput
          optionText={(record: CompoundIndicator) =>
            `${record.external_identifier} @ ${record.version}`
          }
          filterToQuery={(external_identifier) => ({ external_identifier })}
        />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="description" multiline />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-admin has no built-in way to do that. You'll have to create your own component that uses dataProvider hooks like `useGetOne` and `useUpdate`, and react-hook-form hooks like `useForm`.